# Tracing a lost tablet in the house with WiFi on

Tags: samsung, tablet, lost-phone

I have a Samsung tablet with no SIM. The tablet works with our domestic internet connection.   I live in a pretty cluttered house and periodically I misplace the tablet.

Does anyone know of a way of activating the tablet from another computer (on the same network) so as to make it buzz?
This would be so helpful!  Look forward to hearing from somebody.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Find My](https://android.com/find)

If it's a Samsung, you can use [SmartThings find](https://smartthingsfind.samsung.com/)

Comment: Thank you Nicolas. I checked out SmartThings find and I do not think it will actually help too much. It would be ideal for tracing in the world at large; its location definition is within 400 feet apparently. However I am seeking to find a tablet in an house with 5000plus books; and which, I am afraid to say, is quite untidy! If I could somehow make the tablet make a buzzing noise then I am sure this would help.

Comment: But thanks for the suggestion. Regards. Shackec

Comment: @shackec I see there's a "Ring" button on SmartThings find. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, the issue at the moment is that the tablet is somewhere in the house and we cannot find it. Once found I think I will install Smartthings and give it a test. The tablet does not have a SIM so will it have a ring? I do know that it has a buzz of some sort; cannot remember what triggered that!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my wife. I  ended up installing a beacon in each room. I have written an app that tells a server where it was last seen.

In your case I would recommend a tile. Glue it to the tablet. With your phone, you can make the tile scream. It is a pretty piercing noise.

Comment: Thanks Rohiy.  If and when I find the tablet I think a tile might well be the answer. In any event some useful tips which will be useful for the future (once I find the darn thing!)